# Can we use integer as parameters in dictionary data type

Tags: python

```py
def primenumber(**a):
    for i in range(2,a["first"]):
        if((a["first"]%i) == 0):
            break
    if(i == a["first"]):
        print("First Number is prime number in Multiple Asterisk")
    for i in range(2,a["second"]):
        if((a["second"]%i) == 0):
            break
    if(i == a["second"]):
        print("Second Number is prime number in Mutliple Asterisk")
    # pass
primenumber(first = 12,second = 23)
```

It is not showing any output
Can someone help me to know the problem in this code

Comment: @buran I think it's supposed to check if i reached the end of iteration (i.e. `break` didn't happen). Not a good choice, but the indent wouldn't help.

Comment: @matszwecja, yeah right. I deleted my comment

Comment: In what way is the title "Can we use integer as parameters in dictionary data type" related to the actual content of this question?

Answer (score 1):

`i` will never reach the value in the dictionary since `range` is from `start` to `end - 1`. You can switch the `if` with `else` to use `for else` structure

```
def primenumber(**a):
    for i in range(2, a["first"]):
        if a["first"] % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print("First Number is prime number in Multiple Asterisk")
    for i in range(2, a["second"]):
        if a["second"] % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print("Second Number is prime number in Multiple Asterisk")
```

You can also remove duplicate code by using another loop

```
def primenumber(**a):
    for k, v in a.items():
        for i in range(2, v):
            if v % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(f"{k.capitalize()} Number is prime number in Multiple Asterisk")
```

Answer (score 0):

`range` is exclusive of its upper bound, so in the first loop `i` will take the values 2 to 11 (inclusive), thus the post-loop condition will never be true:

```py
>>> list(range(2, 12))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

This is one of relatively few cases where the `else` clause to `for` loops would be useful:

```py
for something in something_else:
    if condition:
        break
else:
    # executes if the loop reached its end and did not `break`
```

The Python style is also somewhat poor e.g.

- Python has no need for parens around conditions, they're just unnecessary noise.
- `**args` are called keyword arguments (possibly variable-arity if you want to be very precise), not "multiple asterisks".
- Here they are either misused or are unnecessary: the entire point of variable arity keyword arguments is to take any number of them, either because they are dynamic or because they're just being forwarded and the current function doesn't really care, this case is likely the former.

Here's a cleaned up version of your function:

```py
def primenumbers(**candidates):
    for label, candidate in candidates.items():
        for candidate_factor in range(2, candidate//2):
            if candidate % candidate_factor == 0:
                break
        else: # no break
            print(f"{label!r} ({candidate}) is a prime number")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the range-function, the starting point is included, and the endpoint is not.
Thus, the highest possible i-value in you for-loop is a["first"] - 1 (or a["second"] -1).
The if-condition is therefore never true.